Returning a list of all values in a column that meet criteria in a different column for the same row
I am tracking information about students. Sheet 1 has each student in their own row, and the columns are different characteristics of that student (for example, their t-shirt size and their grade), as well as their attendance at each session of a class. On Sheet 2, I want to create a stand-alone list of all the students from Sheet 1 who were absent for a given class session. I also want the list on Sheet 2 to update any time there's a change in the column on Sheet 1. For example, if a student was marked here, but was actually absent.
How do I do this?

I have looked into query, vlookup, xlookup, and filters.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Use filter(), like this:
=filter(Sheet1!A4:A, Sheet1!D4:D = "absent")

See filter().
